# YTick overlapping in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been trying to plot data on Matplotlib and I seem to have overlapping YTicks. I am not sure how to adjust them.

**Code**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data= [4270424, 4257372, 4100352, 4100356, 4100356]

plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))

plt.plot(data, 'ko-')
plt.ylabel('Data point')
plt.xlabel('Iteration point')
plt.yticks(data)

plt.margins(0.05, 0.1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

What I wanted is that the numbers to be there, but is it possible to increase the space between the data points?

Comment: Why not just set only three y-ticks? `plt.yticks([4270424, 4257372, 4100356])` You won't increase the space between the data points without changing the data points - the difference doesn't even show in the log-scaling.

Comment: @VlasSokolov I want to actually see the numbers, these minute changes are important.

Comment: I appreciate @VlasSokolov. You can change the data itself (which doesn't make sense), or use a transformation like log. But just plain log doesn't help you in this case either because of the magnitudes and relative differences of your data. You could do `plt.semilogy(data-np.min(data)+1, 'ko-')`, but then you've confused the interpretation, and other points get bunched. If you're focused on the numerical values, maybe you should use a table, in addition to the plot? Or annotate the individual points of interest? Usually when you look at a plot, you're gleaning a general behavior of something.

Comment: @akshay if you really want to keep the labels for every point, consider getting rid of y-ticks altogether. If you annotate individual data points with vertical text labels via `plt.text` will you get a clearer solution to your issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are many close datapoints on y-axis, they overlap. You can avoid showing all of them. You can show only one of too close y-ticks. But the rest can be shown on the plot itself (not on y-axis).

Something like that can be used:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data= [4270424, 4257372, 4100352, 4100356, 4100356]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8))

#Collect only those ticks that are distant enough from each other
#in order to get rid of ticks overlapping on y-axis:
yticks = [min(data)]         
for i in sorted(data[0:]):
  if i-yticks[-1] > 3500:      
    yticks.append(i)          
#################################################################

plt.plot(data, 'ko-')
plt.ylabel('Data point', fontsize=12)
plt.xlabel('Iteration point', fontsize=12)
plt.yticks(yticks)

plt.margins(0.05, 0.1) 


#Showing y-ticks right on the plot
offset = -1.45
x = ax.get_xticks()

for xp, yp in zip(x, data):
    label = "%s" % yp
    plt.text(xp-offset, yp+offset, label, fontsize=12, horizontalalignment='right', verticalalignment='bottom')
#################################

ax.grid()
plt.show()
```

**Output:**
[image]

You can also switch off displaying **yticks** on y-axis completely. In this case change this line `plt.yticks(yticks)` to this: `plt.yticks(yticks, visible=False)`
In this case you don't need ticks collecting part of code at all. But if you keep it, you can turn displaying on later if needed.

Comment: Ya that's one way.  So there is no way to increase the width between the points?